# Returning a lambda capturing a local variable

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, currying

Today I encountered a very unintuitive behavior (for me, at least) in C++11 lambdas. The code in question is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

auto sum(int x) {
    return [&x](int y) {
        return x + y;
    };
}

int main() {
    int a = sum(2)(3);
    printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

Instead of printing 5, this prints gibberish. Actually, at least in my version of GCC, if I turn on the -O2 optimization flag, it actually prints 5. Since the output depends on the optimization level of the compiler, it is undefined behavior. After a while, I think I understood what is happening.

When the function sum is called, a stack variable corresponding to the argument x is set to 2, then the function sum returns, and this stack variable might be overwritten by anything that the compiler needs to put there to execute following code, and by the time the lambda eventually gets executed, the place where x was no longer holds 2, and the program adds 3 to an arbitrary integer.

Is there any elegant way to do currying in C++ guaranteeing that the variable gets captured correctly?

Comment: Capture by value `[=]`.

Comment: Thanks! That was way simpler than I expected.

Comment: Just for the reader, this is C++14, not C++11. Type deduction of function return values was added in C++14.

Comment: I compiled with g++ -std=c++11, and from the output of --version it seems to be from 2013. Maybe this is a non-standard extension of GCC for C++11?

Comment: @FelipeLopes I'm not sure, but [it doesn't work with g++ -std=c++11 here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf5a3f9950fc73ba).

Comment: Here is the full output of --version for my compiler, just in case:
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: type deduction of function return values was so easy, compilers sometimes added it in C++11 before C++14 was finalized, and never bothered taking it out.

Comment: I think it was an extension to GCC that should not be allowed with strict compiler flags

Comment: `Since the output depends on the optimization level of the compiler, it is undefined behavior.` Yeah, it's UB because you used a reference after the lifetime of its referred object had ended. And because it's UB, anything can happen. Different optimisations might produce the same or different code. In fact, the entire program could have been optimised away, as it can be assumed UB never occurs. And time travel! Don't forget that can happen too. But in short, though trying to analyse why it manifests a particular way might be interesting as an exercise, it can't be used to reason about anything

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`int x` has a limited lifetime.  References to automatic storage variables (what you call "the stack") are only valid over the variable's lifetime.  In this case, only until the end of the stack frame (the scope) where the variable exists, or the function for function arguments.

`[&]` captures any mentioned ("local") variable by reference, except `this` (which is captured by value if used or implicitly used).  `[=]` captures any mentioned variable by value.  `[x]` would capture `x` explicitly, and `[&x]` by reference explicitly.  In C++17, `[*this]` also works.

There is also `[x=std::move(x)]`, or `[blah=expression]`.

In general, if the lambda will outlive the current scope don't use `[&]`: be explicit about what you capture.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. Most answers I looked up involving currying on C++ had a lot of template code that I couldn't understand, so I just started trying stuff. Now I know better what I am doing.